# call javascript from servlet in java?

Tags: javascript, java, servlets

I want to call a function of javascript from servlet.

servlet code:

```
File ff = new File(uploadedFile+"/"+fileName+".mp4");

FileOutputStream fileOutSt = new FileOutputStream( ff );

fileOutSt.write(data);

fileOutSt.close();

request.setAttribute("src", ff);

RequestDispatcher dispatcher=request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/jsfunction.js");
dispatcher.include(request, response);
```

**my javascript code:**

```
myfunction(fileInput)
{
  var fileUrl = window.URL.createObjectURL(fileInput);
}
```

The problem is javascript calls but it display the code content but not execute it.
how can i get fileURL.

Comment: Why not invoke html, jsp and import js into it?

Comment: Well you are trying to accomplish something wrongly, I suggest you try a different thing.

Comment: i dont how to invoke html code from servlet. i just want fileUrl but dont know how to get it. can u help.

Comment: can u suggest me another idea

Comment: Well you can put all you html tags along with javascript in it in say a string and can write them to a response using servlets

Comment: i had aalso tried this. it also do the same code is showing in the alert as it is but not execute.

Comment: Well you need to show what you tried in that case

Comment: @monika You seriously want to do a simple thing and failing to explain. Apart from code, can you please tell us what exactly you want to do ?

Comment: @monika, see my updated answer. this way we will get filename from server.

Comment: here don't use `dispatcher` here. see my answer. you need to call the `servlet` from `hml` through `ajax`.@monika.

Answer (score 2):

Several things are wrong here:

First, the inclusion of your javascript source is improper, because the javascript must be included (or referenced) *always within an HTML file*. In your case, instead, you are serving a MP4 file.

If you must *absolutely* execute that js code (remember that js is always executed in a browser), I suggest you serve an HTML page instead. In this case, the jsfunction.js script must be referenced within the HTML code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jsfunction.js" />
</head>
<body>
...
</body>
</html>
```

Second: Even if you include the script, you must then *invoke* your function. You can call it immediately, from a scriptlet, or as a response to some client event (`onclick`, `onload`, etc).

Answer (score 1):

javascript plays on client side and Servlet plays on server side. You cannot execute Javascript on serverside. It should execute by browser.

I suggest you to make a javascript call in window onload.

Answer (score 0):

`RequestDispatcher` interface provides the facility of dispatching the request to another resource it may be `html`, `servlet` or `jsp`. But not to `JS`. Since `JS` always runs in browser itself.

```
request.setAttribute("filename",filenamehere); //put filename    
RequestDispatcher requestDispatcher; 
requestDispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("/filename.jsp");//dispatch here
requestDispatcher.forward(request, response);
```

In `filename.jsp`

```
String value = (String)request.getAttribute("filename");//getting filename
```

Do like this. This way we will get the file url.

**How to pass response from `servlet` to `html`**

Call your `servlet` in same `html` using `ajax` with `jquery`.

In `servlet`

```
    //getting input from `html` page
    String userName = request.getParameter("userName").trim();
    //now process your request here
    //forward response to `html` page
    response.setContentType("text/plain");
    response.getWriter().write("your file url");
```

In `html` call this `servlet` using `ajax`

```
  $.ajax({
        url : 'yourservletaction',
        data : {
            userName : $('#userName').val()//if you want to send any input do like this
        },
        success : function(responseText) {
            $('#ajaxGetUserServletResponse').text(responseText);//getting file url as response. so use this url in you js  
        }
    });
```

Comment: Sir, actually we are using couchDb as document database only. We do not want to store our video in blob format, we just want to convert our video http url to blob http url, just like youtube. i just want to send file object from servelt to javascript. if i am using html then how should i pass the file object. i m really stuck in this problem. plzz help

Comment: @monika, So you suppose to use `jquery` with `ajax`. call your `servlet` with `ajax` in your `html` page. so the response (means file url) this `servlet` will comes your `html` page pass this response to your `js`.

Comment: still all the code are showing in the alert as it is. i m simply calling html from dispatcher and execute jsp written in html.. it is nt execute just display in the alert.

Comment: I Didn't get it. Plz update your code. so that ill see the problem what you are facing.@monika